# Python Program just ends after i typed my number

Tags: python

Everytime when i interpret it and type my number the program just ending. I dont know where the problem is. The console dont even print out an error, so i'm really confused

```
import random

u = input("Schere(1), Stein(2), Papier(3): ")
p = random.randint(1,3)

def spiel(u):
    if u == 1:
     if(p == 2):
        print("PC hat gegen User gewonnen!")
     elif(p == 3):
        print("User hat gegen PC gewonnen!")
     else:
        print("Unentschieden!")

    if u == 2:
     if(p == 3):
        print("PC hat gegen User gewonnen!")
     elif(p == 2):
        print("Unentschieden!")
     else:
        print("User hat gegen PC gewonnen")

    if u == 3:
     if(p == 1):
        print("PC hat gegen User gewonnen!")
     elif(p == 2):
        print("User hat gegen PC gewonnen!")
     else:
        print("Unentschieden!")
```

Comment: You defined a function, but never actually called it.

Comment: You have to have some calling sentence like this, `spiel(u)` after the function definition.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the program quits after you enter your number is because even though you defined the `spiel` function, you never call it, which means that there is a function for how to run the game, but since your program never calls that function, that code never gets run.

You can call your function by adding a line at the end of the program like so:

`spiel(u)`

Comment: i've called it now but it shows still the same like before

Answer (score 0):

`def` defines a function. A function is a separate block of code that can be reused. Every time you want to run the code inside the function block you add `spiel(value)` each time you call it you can change the value.

```
import random

u = input("Schere(1), Stein(2), Papier(3): ")
p = random.randint(1,3)

def spiel(u):
    if u == 1:
     if(p == 2):
        print("PC hat gegen User gewonnen!")
     elif(p == 3):
        print("User hat gegen PC gewonnen!")
     else:
        print("Unentschieden!")

    if u == 2:
     if(p == 3):
        print("PC hat gegen User gewonnen!")
     elif(p == 2):
        print("Unentschieden!")
     else:
        print("User hat gegen PC gewonnen")

    if u == 3:
     if(p == 1):
        print("PC hat gegen User gewonnen!")
     elif(p == 2):
        print("User hat gegen PC gewonnen!")
     else:
        print("Unentschieden!")
spiel(u)
```

Comment: i wrote spiel(u) but it still doesnt work

Comment: What number did you type in?

Comment: i tried number 1-3

Comment: The issue is probably something like "1"!=1

Comment: Then again although I think your function should have acess to the global `p` its better to set it up to pass that too.

Answer (score 0):

You defined `spiel` function without calling it.

You must call it by using `spiel(u)`

Comment: i wrote it. it still doesnt work

Comment: (This answer would be better as a comment.)